# Pros and Cons of ASNA Visual RPG (AVR)

Tags: visual-studio, avr, rpgle

Have you had any experience with ASNA Visual RPG for Visual Studio 2005/2008?  I'm looking for some feedback on this product.  I'm especially curious as to how it compares to other methods of accessing files and programs on the IBM’s System i (formerly known as iSeries, AS/400) server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to ask the RPG-L mailing list this question. You can find it at http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/rpg400-l

Answer (score 1):

I have extensive experience with ASNA's Visual RPG. I currently have around 100 applications running on via windows IIS & accessing data on our iseries. If you have any experience with regular / free form rpg the learning curve should be minimal. If you have any specific questions i'd be glad to help. I've been using visual rpg since August 2005.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I'll keep you in mind next time I run into a problem.